# CSS Text-overflow Ellipsis Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: html, css, web

I have a `<p>` tag to display some information but it should be restricted to 2 lines and if the text is greater then it should show "..." at end. I tried many solutions but i am not able to get exactly what i am looking for. i have tried below css.

```
.mw {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
   line-height: 20px;       
   max-height: 40px;       
   width:100px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

but i am getting three different outputs for three different text in `<p>`.

**TestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTesting**
    [image]

**TestingTesting TestingTestingTestingTesting**
[image]

**TestingTesting TestingTesting TestingTesting**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is caused by the length of the word(s) "TestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTesting"
Using word-wrap (`word-wrap: break-word;`) would alleviate the issue: [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rzq5e/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mw {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: block;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
   line-height: 20px;       
   max-height: 40px;       
   width:100px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p class="mw">
  TestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTesting
</p>
```

use `display: block` for truncation.

**NOTE:** `clamp` css will not work on Firefox and IE

**Ref:** https://caniuse.com/#search=clamp

Answer (score 0):

Add `word-break: break-all;`.

```css
.mw {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
   line-height: 20px;       
   max-height: 40px;       
   width:100px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<p class="mw">TestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTesting</p>

<p class="mw">TestingTesting TestingTestingTestingTesting
</p>

<p class="mw">TestingTesting TestingTesting TestingTesting</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this it will work on all browsers it will ellipsis after two lines.

```css
.mw { 
      display: block;
      /* Fallback for non-webkit */
      display: -webkit-box;
      max-height: 28pt;
      /* Fallback for non-webkit */
      font-size: 10pt;
      line-height: 1.4;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      overflow: hidden;
      -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
      -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

```html
<p class="mw">all long text will come here.all long text will come here.all long text will come here.all long text will come here.all long text will come here.all long text will come here.all long text will come here.all long text will come here.all long text will come here.all long text will come here.</p>
```